# 404 error passing a "Alert" sentence from python to html page, but no error for passing just a word

Tags: html, python-2.7, alert

**Update**: The error message I get with the sentence is 404 Resource not found.

```
"GET /unexpected/The%20Notebook%20name%20is%20taken%20already HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The URL looks like this when that error occurs.

```
http://localhost:8088/unexpected/The%20Notebook%20name%20is%20taken%20already
```

I am attempting very poorly to create a sort of "Alert" system for user errors in my 
application. It appears to me that spaces between words are the problem. But there must be a simple, elegant way to do this.

Of the two lines below, the top one works, but not the bottom one.

```
return webapp2.redirect("/unexpected/%s" % 'Hello')
# return webapp2.redirect("/unexpected/%s" % 'The Notebook name is taken already')
```

The corresponding definition is as follows. Here I would have preferred that the commented 
out line would work, but it will not, either.

```
class Unexpected(BaseHandler):

    def get(self, reason):
        template_values = {'reason':reason}
        path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
        # return webapp2.redirect('/unexpected/%s/ % reason')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage), 
        ('/unexpected/([\w]+)', Unexpected)])
```

How can I get a message sent to the `unexpected.html` page? I have done this before with javascript Alerts, but am trying NOT to use javascript here.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

This unexpected result occurred: {{ reason }}
<br >
Click the back button and edit your entry.

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I am trying to do this in `def get(` without a datastore model to transfer information to the `def get(`. I have defined a `def get(` that uses a datastore model named `Trans` that stores such transactional information that is contained in my sentence in a variable named `reason`.

```
class Trans(db.Model):
    reason = db.StringProperty()
```

My model named `Unexpected` looks like the following.

```
class Unexpected(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
    trans=Trans.get_by_key_name('reason')
    template_values = {'trans':trans}
        path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

And my python codes is as follows.

```
reason='That Notebook name is taken already.'
    trans = Trans(key_name='reason')
    trans.reason=reason
    trans.put()
    template_values = {'trans':trans}
    path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

My `unexpected.html` code follows.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
This unexpected result occurred: <emph style="font-weight: bold">{{ trans.reason }}</emph>
<br /><br />
<label>Click the "Ok" button and to go back to the previous page so you can edit your entry .
</label>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="reason" value=""></input><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Is this actually a solution - an answer to your question? If so, you should accept it. If not, this belongs as an edit to the original question.