# can a javascript "alert" be written in python

Tags: python, http, alert

This question is really a follow on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835306/404-error-passing-a-alert-sentence-from-python-to-html-page-but-no-error-for)

In python how can I make an html alert template know where it came from so it will return there, without making a different template for each exception?

---

I was thinking too much about the javascript "alert" which initiates in the html template, not in the python code. My "alert" starts in the python code itself, so I can just pass a "hidden" variable value to the template which tells where to return and capture that "hidden" value with the "def post" part of the python code.

No, this is still not quite complete. Do I have to import and use that urllib stuff, also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not remotely bulletproof, but checking the [HTTP `Referer` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) sounds sufficient for your needs. If you want more control over the return URL, you can simply pass it around a query parameter instead. Just make sure to [percent-encode it](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote).

Comment: Matt Ball, that link seems to be relevant, but is more focused on the security issue behind HTTP Referrer or Referer headers, not about how to accomplish the "return to sender" part. Can I get more about the how to, please?

Comment: Matt Ball, I didn't see your second link until just now. Is one of the examples at the bottom of that page relevant to me? I am not familiar with urllib. Please also remember I am starting from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835306/404-error-passing-a-alert-sentence-from-python-to-html-page-but-no-error-for)

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the user experience should be? Why isn't the back button sufficient?

Comment: Maybe the back button is sufficient. That's all I really want, but I thought there would be an easy way to provide a more direct "Ok" button.

Comment: You can use JavaScript to programmatically do the same thing as the back button: `<button onclick="window.history.back()">Ok</button>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history

Comment: Removed my comment, I think I got it. I placed your javascript **outside** the <form>. Actually, I may not even need a <form>. Thanks.